# Hbase is freezing after some time

Tags: hbase

We have our hbase application running for few years, now a days it is freezing 3-4 times a day and we have to restart the tomcat to bring our services back to normal. Can you please tell what could be the reason for this failure. Following is the stack trace we are getting:-

```
[2015-07-29 16:11:53,850] WARN246124[pool-1-thread-8] - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1599) - Failed all from region=Session_EG36499597,A95e3582dd-985b-4bbf-8c9c-c3e7378b2c9c~2014111717~B41ea71319-6c87-414e-83e9-3260da33dbce,1429545209762.33fb72a8c67d79dfe2743542b29511a5., hostname=csotg11-dn-rs-tt, port=60020
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Call to csotg11-dn-rs-tt/192.168.1.56:60020 failed on local exception: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatchCallback(HConnectionManager.java:1569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processBatch(HConnectionManager.java:1421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:955)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.doPut(HTable.java:811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool$PooledHTable.put(HTablePool.java:394)
        at egain.DAO.UserDAO.SaveUser(UserDAO.java:156)
        at egain.services.TrackerTask.call(TrackerTask.java:38)
        at egain.asyncManagement.UpdateUserRequest.run(UpdateUserRequest.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Call to csotg11-dn-rs-tt/192.168.1.56:60020 failed on local exception: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.wrapException(HBaseClient.java:1030)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:999)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.multi(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$3$1.call(HConnectionManager.java:1398)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$3$1.call(HConnectionManager.java:1396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withoutRetries(ServerCallable.java:210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$3.call(HConnectionManager.java:1405)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$3.call(HConnectionManager.java:1393)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:473)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:114)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.sendParam(HBaseClient.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:86)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.openScanner(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool$PooledHTable.getScanner(HTablePool.java:378)
        at egain.models.HBaseConnectionFactory.getScanner(HBaseConnectionFactory.java:313)
        at egain.DAO.SessionDAO.getSession(SessionDAO.java:44)
        at egain.DAO.SessionDAO.getCompleteDataForSession(SessionDAO.java:109)
        at egain.utils.eGainParser.getBySessionId(eGainParser.java:54)
        at egain.services.DataTask.call(DataTask.java:52)
        at egain.services.DataTask.call(DataTask.java:1)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Did you get answer or solution for this i am facing the similar issue